# Django ignoring changes in urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I've read just about everything I found online about this problem but found no solution. When I make changes to my core/urls.py file, the changes are just ignored (core is my main app name). When I make changes to the project level urls.py, the changes are loaded just fine. It's the app level urls.py, that's being ignored. I am running on wsgi/apache2. I tried restarting apache2, stopping it, deleting the urls.pyc file, touching the urls.py file, and starting apache2 again. None of this helped. I also tried to touch the wsgi.py file, to no avail. Any ideas what else could it be?

Comment: let's start with obvious - have you included your app's urls into project's urls.py like that url(r'^', include('core.urls', namespace="core"))? you probably did, but to be sure

Comment: Yes, I did that. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: And I made sure the app is inside INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, I just found it - thanks to your post, Alex! I was including it like this:

```
url(r'^$', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
```

instead of like this:

```
url(r'', include('core.urls', namespace='core')),
```

So I was excluding the include for all URLs other than the root /.

Thanks for having me look again and more carefully!